# Create a single NuGet package from loosely coupled service host/services solution

Tags: .net, nuget

I have a solution with three projects, A, B and C. A is a service host and B and C are service assemblies. None of the projects (unfortunately) reference each other in the solution and I cannot change this fact right now. What I am trying to do is to create a NuGet package containing A, B and C. I know I can create a custom NuSpec-file for A and manually list all the the dll's in the file-section that I want in my package, but I am wondering if there is any way to tell NuGet to treat A and B as referenced projects (even though they are not)? This would allow me to use the option -IncludeReferencedProjects when creating my package with pack.

The obvious solution would be to create a dependency in my solution between A, B and C but the current solution defines a kind of loosely coupled system with service/service assemblies where the number of available services can differ between different installations.

Comment: This sounds very strange. If they're meant to be decoupled, then why do you need a Nuget package containing all of them referenced together? And if they need to be referenced together, why not just do it in the solution? Looking for the *why* here to help with the objective rather than the method.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The reason they need to be coupled in the NuGet package is because I want to be able to deploy them using Octopus Deploy. The package should contain everything needed to successfully run the "backend service". All of the installations will have A, B and C in a bundle.

Comment: why don't you create three different nuget packages and reference each ?

Comment: @EmilG it seems it would be easier to just package them individually (the way they're designed) and then reference them in a new 4th project that can be what you use for deployment.

Comment: @ManiGandham: Thank you, I will try that approach.